# I wrote a script for movement and mouse look, movement works but mouse look does not

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am writing a script for movement and mouselook, the movement works but the mouse look does not. I start the game, the cursor locks into the game screen and I can move but I can't look around and there are no bugs. can someone help?

Here is my script:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player_Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]private float _speed = 7f;
    [SerializeField]private float _mouseSensitivity = 50f;
    [SerializeField]private float _minCameraview = -70f, _maxCameraview = 80f;
    private CharacterController _charController;
    private Camera _camera;
    private float xRotation = 0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        _charController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        _camera = Camera.main;

        if(_charController == null)
        Debug.Log("No Character Controller Attached to Player");

        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Get WASD Input for Player
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        //move player based on WASD Input
        Vector3 movement = Vector3.forward * vertical + Vector3.right * horizontal;
        _charController.Move(movement * Time.deltaTime * _speed);


        
        //Get Mouse position Input
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * _mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * _mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
          //Rotate the camera based on the Y input of the mouse
          xRotation -= mouseY;
          //clamp the camera rotation between 80 and -70 degrees
          xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, _minCameraview, _maxCameraview);

          _camera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0, 0);
          //Rotate the player based on the X input of the mouse
          transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX * 3);

    }
}
```

Comment: Does it have buggy movement, or does it not rotate at all?

Comment: it does not have buggy movement but it doesn't rotate and doesn't look around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are multiplying the mouse input by `Time.deltaTime`. `Time.deltaTime` is used when you want to have different devices with different frame rates. This is because when multiplying by `Time.deltaTime`, you get a constant speed of one unit per second:

```cs
float speed = 10f;
float movement = speed * Time.deltaTime;
```

If you have a frame rate of 10fps (hopefully you don't), you would have each frame in 0.1 second. Each frame is 0.1 second, so when multiplying it by 10 (the speed), you get a value of one. If you speed the frame rate up, you would also get 10 units a second (1 x 10 = 10).

The mouse movement doesn’t need this because mouse movement is not handled by the computer. In other words, when you are moving the mouse, it isn’t changing by the frame rate, so you don’t need ‘Time.deltaTime`.

I also noticed that your movement was based on `Vector3`. What I mean by this is that you were using global coordinates rather than local (transform). This means if the play rotates, `Vector3.forward` will be different than the player’s forward. You should use `transform.forward` instead to use local coordinates.

You should change the script to this:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player_Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]private float _speed = 7f;
    [SerializeField]private float _mouseSensitivity = 50f;
    [SerializeField]private float _minCameraview = -70f, _maxCameraview = 80f;
    private CharacterController _charController;
    private Camera _camera;
    private float xRotation = 0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        _charController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        _camera = Camera.main;

        if(_charController == null)
        Debug.Log("No Character Controller Attached to Player");

        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Get WASD Input for Player
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        //move player based on WASD Input
        Vector3 movement = transform.forward * vertical + transform.right * horizontal; //changed this line.
        _charController.Move(movement * Time.deltaTime * _speed);


        
        //Get Mouse position Input
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * _mouseSensitivity; //changed this line.
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * _mouseSensitivity; //changed this line.
          //Rotate the camera based on the Y input of the mouse
          xRotation -= mouseY;
          //clamp the camera rotation between 80 and -70 degrees
          xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, _minCameraview, _maxCameraview);

          _camera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0, 0);
          //Rotate the player based on the X input of the mouse
          transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX * 3);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi ken, It didn't fix the mouse problem for me, I changed the lines you've asked me to, but it is still the same, I am not getting any errors

Comment: Do you have any other scripts in your game? I actually made a unity project with this code in it, and it worked for me. You might be controlling  the camera from somewhere else. What does your hierarchy look like?

Comment: it has the map, FPS player, Lights for main prototype place, Terrain, Exit Hatch room map terrain, Canvas, Snaps_level, Scene Lights, Rock Mesh.

Comment: but it says NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Player_Controller.Update () (at Assets/Player_Controller.cs:46)

Comment: Okay, a NullReferenceException occurs when you are trying to access an undefined variable. You probably don't have the `_camera` variable set in the inspector. I don't know why you don't have it set because it is set in the start. Do you have multiple cameras? Try setting the `_camera` variable public and then drag the right camera in the inspector into the slot.

Comment: I don't have multiple cameras and I set the _camera variable set in the inspector and it is public, but it still is not working.

Comment: Do you still get the NoReferenceException? I think the camera isn't being set. Try removing the line in the start function that says `_camera = Camera.main`. Somewhere the `_camera` isn't being set, yet I use the same code and it doesn't happen to me. Try copying and pasting the exact thing I put in my code.

Comment: which part should I copy and paste Ken,

Comment: Copy the code in my answer. If it doesn't work, try adding the camera through the inspector and removing the statement in Start that says `_camera = Camera.main`.

Comment: I have checked the inspector when i start the game, and it is not set to the camera, it is set to none but I have already set the camera before starting the game, I don't know why it is doing that, when in game, I set the camera because itis not set, the camera works.

Comment: I think it is because of the statement in the start function that sets the `_camera = Camera.main`. It will override what you set it to in the inspector. Delete that line. For me it is line 18.

Comment: its working, thanks for the help, sorry it was a bit long. thanks for the help Ken.

Comment: Please close the question or accept the answer to signal to other developers that you found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a script for  both movement and looking

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float walkingSpeed = 7.5f;
    public float runningSpeed = 11.5f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0f;
    public float gravity = 20.0f;
    public Camera playerCamera;
    public float lookSpeed = 2.0f;
    public float lookXLimit = 45.0f;

    CharacterController characterController;
    Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    float rotationX = 0;

    [HideInInspector]
    public bool canMove = true;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        // Lock cursor
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }



// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
    {
        // We are grounded, so recalculate move direction based on axes
        Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        Vector3 right = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right);
        // Press Left Shift to run
        bool isRunning = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift);
        float curSpeedX = canMove ? (isRunning ? runningSpeed : walkingSpeed) * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") : 0;
        float curSpeedY = canMove ? (isRunning ? runningSpeed : walkingSpeed) * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") : 0;
        float movementDirectionY = moveDirection.y;
        moveDirection = (forward * curSpeedX) + (right * curSpeedY);

        if (Input.GetButton("Jump") && canMove && characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            moveDirection.y = movementDirectionY;
        }

        // Apply gravity. Gravity is multiplied by deltaTime twice (once here, and once below
        // when the moveDirection is multiplied by deltaTime). This is because gravity should be applied
        // as an acceleration (ms^-2)
        if (!characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        // Move the controller
        characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);

        // Player and Camera rotation
        if (canMove)
        {
            rotationX += -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * lookSpeed;
            rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(rotationX, -lookXLimit, lookXLimit);
            playerCamera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationX, 0, 0);
            transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * lookSpeed, 0);
        }
    }
}
```